# Problem when using limit in MySQL with MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, limit, offset

I have a problem:
I am using SQL Query in php like this function

```
public function getLisIndex($a= array()){
      $db = $this->getSlaveDB();
      $sql = "SELECT cv.number,
                     cv.date,                   
              FROM cv1
              INNER JOIN cv ON cv1.id= cv.id              
              ORDER BY cv.year DESC, cv.date DESC, cv.number DESC
              LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
    return $db->fetchAll($sql, $a);
  }
```

When running in XAMPP, using PDO, this code return error in LIMIT and OFFSET.
How fix that problem?
Thanks very much!

Comment: You have placeholders for the LIMIT and OFFSET values but you never bind any values to them resulting in an invalid SQL query. You also never actually execute the query before you try to fetch the results.

Comment: LIMIT an OFFSET bind by fetchAll function 
public function fetchAll($sql, $params = array())
    {
        $statement = $this->_query($sql, $params);
        return $statement->fetchAll($this->_fetchMode);
    }

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using here? I remember that older versions didn't support binding to the LIMIT parameters (but I don't remember when this actually got supported).

One workaround would be to use PDO client side emulated statements with PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php